# MediaPlayer caching is not working

Tags: android, video

I have a `ViewPager` with items extending from `FrameLayout`, each one of them represents a video. Code for initialization:

```
            try {
                mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), Uri.parse(mVideo.getVideo().getPreviewMedium().getUrl()));
                mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mOnPreparedListener);
                mPlayer.prepareAsync();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.toLog(e);
            }
```

And in `onPrepared` :

```
            mPlayer.start();
```

As i know, `ViewPager` is trying to initialize 3 items : current, previous and next, so if i'm switching between these 3 it works fine, but if i'm going further and then reurning back - video is loading again after `mPlayer.setDataSource`

**Question:** Is there any chance to cache it after first setup, so future calls of `mPlayer.setDataSource` will work instantly?

Comment: use a arraylist in viewpager to cache status.

Comment: @tinysunlight, status of what? And how it will help, i need some info on your suggestion please

Comment: Maybe you can set a large offsetlimit on viewpager.

Comment: @tinysunlight, But there could be a lot of videos, and i can't do it because of it. OutOfMemory pretty much can happen

Comment: Do you release mediaplayer after change page?

Comment: @tinysunlight, Yes, i do. It happens in DetachFromWindow method

Answer (score 0):

viewpager.`setoffsetlimit()` to the  size of you item.

Use is prepared to check if is prepared.If it's prepared , you neednt't setData.

Comment: as @Nik mentioned his problem is not about size viewpager when he swipe between pages fragments view is destroyed so mediaPlayer start from beginning. I think increase size of viewpager doesnt help him